# How to remove emoji characters in excel?

Tags: excel, emoji

I would like to remove all the emoji characters in an excel spreadsheet. I know they are under char(63) which is not easy to tackle. I know some people will just remove all the special characters that are outside a-z and 0-9, but it doesn't solve my problem because my spreadsheet may have many other foreign languages like Chinese, Thai.

Comment: You'll need to check the current specifications, but I believe that Unicode emojis are in a range of unicode `1F600` and higher (the Emoticon block). You just need to remove those characters with the unicodes of the Emoticon block..

Comment: Sorry i still can't get it, how to implement in Excel?

Comment: i can use a =SUBSTITUTE(A16, UNICHAR(128142), "") formula to remove specific emoji, but how to remove all the emojis that has UNICHAR higher than 12xxxx?